# Asymptotic (divergent) series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, reference-request, divergent-series

MOTIVATION. After having read in detail an article by Alf van der Poorten  I read a very short paper by Roger Apéry. I am interested in finding a proof of a series expansion in the latter, which is in not given in it. So *I assumed it should be stated or derived from a theorem on the subject*.

In Apéry, R., *Irrationalité de $\zeta 2$ et $\zeta
3$,* Société Mathématique de France, Astérisque 61 (1979)
there is a *divergent* series expansion for a function I would like to
understand. Here is my translation of the relevant part for this question

> *(...) given a real sequence $a_{1},a_{2},\ldots ,a_{k}$, an analytic function $f\left( x\right) $ with respect to the variable
>   $\frac{1}{x}$ tending to $0$ with $\frac{1}{x}$ admits a (unique)
>   expansion in the form* $$f\left( x\right) \equiv \sum_{k\geq
> 1}\frac{c_{k}}{\left( x+a_{1}\right) \left( x+a_{2}\right) \ldots
>  \left( x+a_{k}\right) }.\tag{A}$$

Added copy of the original:

[image]

and the translation by Generic Human of the text after the formula:

> "*(We write ≡ instead of = to take into account the aversions of
>   mathematicians who, following Abel, Cauchy and d'Alembert, hold
>   divergent series to be an invention of the devil; in fact, we only
>   ever use a finite sum of terms, but the number of terms is an
>   unbounded function of x.)*"

*Remark*. As far as I understand, based on this last text, the expansion of $f(x)$ in $(\mathrm{A})$ is in general   a *divergent* series and not a convergent one, but the existing answer [by WimC] seems to indicate the opposite.

The corresponding finite sum appears and is proved in section 3 of Alfred van der Poorten's article *[A proof that Euler missed ... Apéry's proof of the irrationality of $\zeta (3)$](http://maths.mq.edu.au/~alf/Humid%20Summer/45.pdf)* as

> *For all $a_{1}$, $a_{2}$, $\dots$*  $$ \sum_{k=1}^{K}\frac{a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{k-1}}{(x+a_{1})(x+a_{2})\cdots(x+a_{k})}= \frac{1}{x}-\frac{a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{K}}{x(x+a_{1})(x+a_{2})\cdots(x+a_{K})},$$
>   $$\tag{A'} $$

**Questions:**

1. Is series $(A)$ indeed divergent?
2. Which is the theorem stating or from which expansion $(\mathrm{A})$ can be derived?
3. Could you please indicate a reference?

---

I've [posted](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94733/divergent-series-expansion-in-aperys-proof-of-the-irrationality-of-zeta2-an) on MathOverflow a variant of this question.

Comment: Related [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/131026/752) and [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131004/proving-an-amazing-claim-regarding-zeta-3-and-aperys-proof).

Comment: For those who do not know what Apéry wrote after the formula $(A)$ it can be found [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sGRHk.jpg).

Comment: Translation: *"We write $\equiv$ instead of $=$ to take into account the aversions of mathematicians who, following Abel, Cauchy and d'Alembert, hold divergent series to be an invention of the devil; in fact, we only ever use a finite sum of terms, but the number of terms is an unbounded function of $x$."*

Comment: @GenericHuman Thanks for the translation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Writing $g_1(x)=f(1/x)$ gives
$$
g_1(x)\equiv\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{c_kx^k}{(1+a_1x)(1+a_2x)\dots(1+a_kx)}\tag{1}
$$
which vanishes at $x=0$.

Recursively define
$$
g_{n+1}(x)=\frac{(1+a_nx)g_n(x)}{x}-c_n\tag{2}
$$
where
$$
c_n=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g_n(x)}{x}\tag{3}
$$
Then
$$
g_n(x)\equiv\sum_{k\ge n}\frac{c_kx^{k-n+1}}{(1+a_nx)(1+a_{n+1}x)\dots(1+a_kx)}\tag{4}
$$
is another series like $(1)$ (which vanishes at $x=0$).

The series in $(1)$ may or may not converge, as with the [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula). As with most asymptotic series, we are only interested in the first several terms; the remainder (not the remaining terms) can be bounded by something smaller than the preceding terms. Therefore, convergence is not an issue.

Answer (score 4):

This formula might be easier to understand if it is expressed for $x$ (instead of $\tfrac{1}{x}$) near $0$.  Let the sequence $a_1, a_2, \dotsc$ be given.  For an analytic $f$ with $f(0)=0$ it then says that there exist $c_1, c_2, \dotsc$ such that

$$
f(x) \equiv \sum_{k \geq 1}\frac{c_kx^k}{(1+a_1x)\cdots(1+a_kx)}
$$

Now $(1+a_1x)f(x)$ also vanishes at $x=0$ so

$$
\frac{(1+a_1x)f(x)}{x} = c_1 + b_1x + b_2x^2 + \dotsc
$$

which gives you $c_1$.  Repeat the process with

$$
\frac{(1+a_1x)f(x)}{x} - c_1
$$

to find $c_2$, and so on.  I don't have any references though, and browsing through the references you provided I just wonder: how can people get such wonderful ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't it be 

$$\frac{(1+a_{1}x)f(x)}{x}=c_{1}+\frac{c_{2}}{1+a_{2}x}x+\frac{c_{3}}{\left(
1+a_{2}x\right) \left( 1+a_{3}x\right) }x^{2}+\ldots \; ?$$

Comment: If you are right, it seems to me that the series would be convergent.

Comment: @AméricoTavares About your first comment: sure, but I wanted to pick off the coefficients one by one.  That's why I used some other names ($b_j$).  The $\equiv$ is also clear by just noting that

$$
\frac{x^k}{(1+a_1x)\cdots(1+a_kx)} = x^k + o(x^k)
$$

which shows that you can construct the coefficients of $f$ one by one since you leave lower order terms unchanged.

Comment: @AméricoTavares About convergence: what is the radius of convergence of each term?  Of each partial sum?  What happens if $|a_k| \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comment. So far I understand your $b_{1}$, $b_{2}$ are $b_{1}=c_{2}/\left( 1+a_{2}x\right) $, $b_{2}=c_{3}/\left((1+a_{2}x)(1+a_{3}x)\right)$, etc. I've expanded $b_{1}$ as $$b_{1}=\frac{c_{2}}{1+a_{2}x}=c_{2}+\left( -c_{2}a_{2}\right) x+O\left(x^{2}\right).$$ Hence $$b_{1}x=c_{2}\frac{x}{1+a_{2}x}=c_{2}x+\left( -c_{2}a_{2}\right)x^{2}+O\left( x^{3}\right).$$ And I think I could write these as $$b_{1}=c_{2}+\left( -c_{2}a_{2}\right)x+o\left( x^{2}\right)$$ and $$b_{1}x=c_{2}x+\left( -c_{2}a_{2}\right) x^{2}+o\left( x^{3}\right).$$ Is my understanding right?

Comment: @AméricoTavares The coefficients $b_j$ are not that important.  In fact I could have simply written $c_1 + o(1)$.  The essential part is to understand that this step by step process *will* uniquely generate the coefficients $c_k$, whatever their exact values.  I sketched another (less explicit) way to look at this in an earlier comment.

Comment: Thanks again! If $|a_{k}|\rightarrow \infty $, I'm not sure if the following limit is $0$ but judging from your comments it seems they are 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^{k}}{\left( 1+a_{1}x\right) \cdots \left(
1+a_{k}x\right) }.$$

Also I've computed 

$$\frac{(1+a_{1}x)f(x)}{x}=c_{1}+\sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{c_{k}x^{k-1}}{\left(
1+a_{2}x\right) \cdots \left( 1+a_{k}x\right) }.
$$

Comment: +1, Thank you very much! Most likely your argument is completely right. I have to convince myself because I am not quite sure. I will not comment further because the message "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" appeared. A last request: would you mind editing your proof to add your comments and/or additional details?

Comment: As an example, would you mind finding the first few terms of the function(s) $x\mapsto 1/x^2$ or $x\mapsto 1/x^3$ ?

Comment: For $f(x)=1/x^2$ the coefficients are $0, 1, a_1+a_2, a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_2a_3, \dotsc$.  That is, $c_k$ is the coefficient of $x^2$ in the polynomial $\prod_{j=1}^k(x+a_j)$.  More generally, for $f(x)=1/x^m$ it turns out that $c_k$ is the coefficient of $x^m$ in that polynomial.

Comment: Thanks! Apéry obtained the following expansions
$$\begin{equation*}\frac{1}{n^{2}}\equiv\frac{1}{n\left( n-1\right) }-\frac{1}{n\left(n-1\right) \left( n-2\right) }+\cdots +\frac{\left( -1\right) ^{k-1}}{n\left( n-1\right)\left( n-2\right) \cdots \left( n-k-1\right) }+\cdots\end{equation*}$$
and
$$\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{n^{3}}\equiv\frac{1}{n\left( n^{2}-1\right) }-\frac{1}{n\left(
n^{2}-1\right) \left( n^{2}-4\right) }+\cdots +\frac{\left( -1\right)^{k}\left( k!\right) ^{2}}{n\left( n^{2}-1\right) \cdots \left(n^{2}-\left(k-1\right) ^{2}\right) }+\cdots 
\end{equation*}$$

Comment: ... I've checked the second by the technique described in Alf van der Poorten's
article. As for the 1st one I've got a similar but not quite the same
expansion.

Comment: It appears that a factor $k!$ is missing in the first one.  The numerator should be $(-1)^k k!$ (for $k = 0, 1, \dotsc$).

Comment: I am sorry. I transcribed the formula incorrectely. In the original it is $$\begin{equation*}
\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\equiv\dfrac{1}{n\left(n-1\right) }-\dfrac{1}{n\left(n-1\right) \left( n-2\right) }+\cdots +\dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}k!}{
n\left(n-1\right)\left(n-2\right)\cdots\left( n-k-1\right) }+\cdots\end{equation*}$$

Comment: Please excuse me by asking if the expansion for $f(x)$ is a divergent or a convergent series. I thought based on an remark in Apéry's paper it was divergent but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure Apéry was really saying the series was divergent: I think he was just explaining the notation and saying that if convergence is not *proven*, then it is useful to have a notation that doesn't imply convergence.

- For non-negative $a_i$ and positive $x$, you can check that if $f(1/t)=\sum_{k\ge 1} b_k t^k$ ($t=1/x$), we have
  $$c_k=\sum_{i=1}^k b_i\left([x^{i-1}]\prod_{j=1}^{k-1} x+a_j\right)$$
  Since all coefficients are non-negative:
  $$\prod_{j=1}^{k-1} 1/t+a_j\ge 1/t^{i-1} [x^{i-1}] \prod_{j=1}^{k-1} x+a_j$$
  Thus $$\left|\frac{c_k}{\prod_{j=1}^k 1/t+a_j}\right|\le \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{|b_i| t^i}{1+a_k t}\le \sum_{i=1}^k |b_i| t^i$$
  which proves convergence of the series whenever $t$ is less than the radius of convergence of $f(1/t)$.
- For negative $a_i$, pick $a_i=-2^i$ and $f(1/t)=1/t$, the series is:
  $$\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{1/a_k}{\prod_{i=1}^k 1+1/(ta_i)}$$
  which is absolutely convergent for $t\ne -1/a_j$ and equivalent around $t\rightarrow -1/a_j$ to
  $$\frac 1{\prod_{i=1}^j 1+1/(ta_i)}\sum_{k\ge j} \frac{1/a_k}{\prod_{i=j+1}^k 1-a_j/a_i}$$
  which diverges as $t\rightarrow -1/a_j$. So there is an open set around $-1/a_j$ where the series does not converge to $f(1/t)$ and the series cannot converge to $f(1/t)$ in a neighborhood of $+\infty$, not even almost everywhere.

Comment: For those who do not know what Apéry wrote after the formula $(A)$ it can be found [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sGRHk.jpg).