# Another Question based on Abel's theorem of multiplication of series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to show that the $qth$ power of the series $$a_{1}\sin \theta +a_{2}\sin 2\theta +\ldots +a_{n}\sin n\theta +...$$ is convergent whenever $q(1-r)<1$, r being the greatest number satisfying the relation $a_{n}\leq n^{-r }$ for all values of $n$.

My immediate thoughts were to multiply the series and rearrange the terms as [Abel's rule](https://planetmath.org/abelsmultiplicationruleforseries) and then follow along in the footsteps of the brilliant solution posted by André Nicolas [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123769/question-based-on-abels-theorem-of-multiplication-of-series), but i am having a hard time determining what general term in the $qth$ product series looks like. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by $q$-th power of a series?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I believe the qth power refers to multiplying the series by itself q number of times and obtaining a new qth power series of the original series. This is used as the scene for Abels' rule. In the question there is a link to the theorem, which may provide some more context. I hope this is helpfull.

Comment: By $q$th power of series, I believe that you are referring to [Cauchy product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product). In that case it doesn't make any sense(at least to me) to define it for $q$ being anything other than natural numbers.

Comment: As with your other Question about Abel's rule, I'm suggesting fixing the broken link with this replacement: [Abel's multiplication rule for series](https://planetmath.org/abelsmultiplicationruleforseries).

Comment: I went ahead and made the replacement.  Please review that I've not unintentionally changed your meaning.

Answer (score -1):

This problem is modified from the problem in the paper titled "On the Multiplication and Involution of Semi-Convergent Series" by Florian Cajori. Here is the link.

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2369794?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents

See P204.

Comment: When answering with a link to an external site, it is the guideline to quote the most relevant material to be found at the URL and/or to summarize that in your own words so Readers can judge whether to follow the link (and to help reconstructing the link if it becomes broken).  See the FAQ on [how to write a good answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) under **Provide context for links**.