# $y_1, y_2, y_3$ are particular solutions of $y'+a(x)y=b(x)$, so the function $\frac{y_2-y_3}{y_3-y_1}$ is constant.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'd really love your help with the following exercise.

I need to show that if $y_1, y_2, y_3$ are particular solutions of the linear equation:

$y'+a(x)y=b(x)$, so the function $$\frac{y_2-y_3}{y_3-y_1}$$ is constant.

I got that a particular solution should be of the form: $e^{-\int_{x_0}^{x}a(s)ds}c(x)$, where $c'(x)=e^{\int_{x_0}^{x}a(s)ds}b(x)$. what else should I do? How should I solve this one?

Thanks!

Comment: What's a private solution?

Comment: I meant that they denote the equation.

Comment: @Hans I think he means particular solutions or something of the sort (in contrast with the general solution)

Comment: I think it looks easier to prove that $\ln \frac{y_2-y_3}{y_3-y_1}$ is constant by derivating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $y_1$ and $y_2$ are both particular solutions to
$$y' + a(x)y = b(x)$$
then $y_1-y_2$ is a solution to the associated homogeneous differential equation
$$y' + a(x)y = 0.$$

Indeed, we have
$$\begin{align*}
(y_1-y_2)' + a(x)(y_1-y_2) &= y_1'-y_2 + a(x)y_1 - a(x)y_2\\
 &= (y_1'+a(x)y_1)-(y_2'+a(x)y_2)\\
 &= b(x)-b(x)=0.
\end{align*}$$

In your situation, you then have the quotient of two (nonzero) solutions to the homogeneous equation
$$y' + a(x)y = 0.$$

This is separable, and a solution to this equation is of the form $Ae^{\int a(x)\,dx}$ for some constant $A$. So what you have is a quotient of the form
$$\frac{A_1 e^{\int a(x)\,dx}}{A_2e^{\int a(x)\,dx}} = \frac{A_1}{A_2}.$$

Comment: If $y_i' + a(x)y_i = 0$ then $\frac{y'_1}{y_1}-\frac{y'_2}{y_2}=0$ thus $\ln y_1-\ln y_2$ is constant... Of course this is the same as your computation, but looks nicer...

Comment: @N.S. Sometimes the math is ugly.

Comment: @Dear Arturo Magidin, I know it is not the right place because it is rather off-topic, but would you mind having a look at my last question [123632](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123632/divergent-series-expansion-in-aperys-proof-of-the-irrationality-of-zeta2-a)? If necessary I will remove this comment.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

Differentiate the given quotient and replace $y_i'$ with $-ay_i+b$ for $i=1,2,3$ and you'll see that everything cancels.

Comment: Are you sure? It didn't work for me..

Comment: @Jozef: You must have made an error; the numerator cancels for me.

Answer (score 3):

Just thought I'd add the quotient rule worked out:

$$\left(\frac{y_2-y_3}{y_3-y_1}\right)'=\frac{(y_2-y_3)'(y_3-y_1)-(y_2-y_3)(y_3-y_1)'}{(y_3-y_1)^2}$$

$$=\frac{\big(a(x)(\color{Blue}{y_3-y_2})\big)(\color{Green}{y_3-y_1})-(\color{Blue}{y_2-y_3})\big(a(x)(\color{Green}{y_1-y_3})\big)}{(y_3-y_1)^2}=0. $$